# Nginx static resource address

Tags: nginx

Translation
The project is placed in the "nginx/html" folder. I have the following configuration in the nginx.conf file:

```
location /project1 {
    root html;
    index  index.html;
}

location /project2 {
    root html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

I can access each project correctly. However, when accessing static resources, all project's static resource lookup paths are "html". For example:

Request: "GET /js/app.c930e0fe.js HTTP/2.0", referrer: "website/project1"

The expected path should be "html/project1/js/app.c930e0fe.js", but the actual path is "html/js/app.c930e0fe.js".

Can you help me with this?

Attempt 1:
I tried the following configuration, but it still looks for static resources in the "html" folder:

```
location /project1 {
    alias html/project1;
    index index.html;
}

location /project2 {
    alias html/project2;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Attempt 2:
I attempted to add the project path in front of static resources using the referrer variable, but it didn't work:

```
map $http_referer $referrer_path {
    "~^my website/(.*)/$" /$1;
}
```

Attempt 3:
I also tried the following configuration to customize the lookup path for static resources, but it still looks for them in the "html" folder:

```
location ~* \.(js|css|woff|jpg|png|woff2)$ {
    if ($request_uri ~ "^/([^?]*)") {
        set $request_path $1;
    }

    if ($http_referer ~* "^my website/([^?]*)") {
        set $referrer_path $1;
    }
    set $resource_path "html/$referrer_path/$request_path";
    try_files =404 /$resource_path;
}
```